# Tinymce-4 how to add menutime dynamically?

Tags: tinymce-4

I am trying to add a menuitem to the menu of a menubutton.

The console.log show that the item is added but the menu doesnt render the new option.

```
tinymce.init(
  { 
    selector:'textarea',
    toolbar: ['btnNombres'],
    menubar: false,
    setup: function (editor) {
      var itemsNombre = [
                {
                    text: 'Adicionar',
                    name: 'mn_nombre_adicionar',
                    onclick: function(event){
            this._parent.add({text:'Test', type:'menuitem'});
            console.log(this._parent._items);
                    }                   
                }
            ];
      editor.addButton('btnNombres', {
                type: 'menubutton',
                text: 'Nombre',
                tooltip: 'Nombres',
                menu: itemsNombre
            });
    }
  }
);
```

I expected to have a new item in the menubutton but there is none.  [CodePen](https://codepen.io/aldoherrera/pen/OqejQg)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I have to do is change:

```
this._parent.add({text:'Test', type:'menuitem'});
```

for

```
this._parent.append({text:'Test', type:'menuitem'});
```